# WordPress Customise page keeps reloading after applying child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just created a new child theme and here is my source code which I followed the official WordPress [Child Themes document](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

`style.css`

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   Astra Child Theme
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Astra Child Theme
 Author:       xxx
 Author URI:   https://...
 Template:     astra
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  astra
*/
```

`funtions.php`

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( 'parenthandle' ), 
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

I have tried different declarations for `functions.php` I can't find a reason why customise page, Elementor page, etc. they can be loaded correctly as customise page will be just auto-reloading which can be observed from the [network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tbRY.png) and Elementor will just be loading like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfVSB.png).

---

Therefore, I am here asking for help and thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Astra actually has its own child theme for use. Though most of the issues you are experience are related to JS. Make sure WordPress and Plugins are updated. With all the changes and with WordPress pushing for updated jQuery if you are using outdated plugins it could cause issues.

```
<?php
/**
 * Astra Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, 'all' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );
```